# Primary key couple unique in both ways

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my problem :

I want to create relations between two items of the same type.

Basically, I have a 'tag' table and I want to establish relations between tags.

I created a table 'tag_relations'. In this table, each line would represent one relation. It will be composed with 2 atributes : tag_id (which is the id of the tag concerned by the relation), and relation (which is the id of the tag related to the first tag represented by tag_id).

I set the primary key of my 'tag_relations' table as the couple of these 2 attributes.

Here is how I created my table :

```
CREATE TABLE `tag_relation` (
  `tag_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `relation` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`tag_id`,`relation`),
  KEY `relation` (`relation`),
  CONSTRAINT `tag_relation_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`tag_id`) REFERENCES `tag` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `tag_relation_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`relation`) REFERENCES `tag` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

My question is : how can I make sure, if I already have a couple (1,2) in my table (so tag 1 is related to tag 2), that it's impossible for me to insert the couple (2,1) (because this relation would already exist implicitly).

Am I forced to create a trigger ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some databases support indexes on expressions.  Since 5.7, MySQL has generated columns with indexes.  This allows you to do:

```
alter table tag_relation add tag1 generated always as (least(tag1, relation));
alter table tag_relation add tag2 generated always as (greatest(tag1, relation));

create unique index unq_tag_relation_tag1_tag2 on tag_relation(tag1, tag2);
```

In earlier versions, you would need an `insert` (and possibly `update`) trigger to ensure data integrity.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood what tag1 and tag2 represent. Are they column names ?
And to my knowledge, least returns the lowest value. How is it relevant in my case? Because if I understood correctly, you would want to block the insertion of 2,1 if 1,2 is already existing, but what if 2,1 is already inserted ?

Comment: @StéphaneConq . . . These a generated (or computed) columns that contain the smaller and larger value.  These are then used for the unique index.